# How do I know how many users go to page C from page A through page B using Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

Let's say I have a shop where the shopper have to login first, for the sake of example. There is a page called `/cart` where users can see all of the products they added to the cart from previous pages and proceed with the checkout. If the user is not logged in yet the `/cart` will go to `/login` and then will go to `/success`. Otherwise it will go to `/success` directly.

Using Google Analytics, how do I know

1. How many users want go to through the trouble of putting their credentials to process the cart?
2. How many users don't want to do it?
3. How many users that are already logged in, i.e. don't go through the `/login`? (assuming I don't track the user type using Custom Variables).

Answer (score 2):

Google Analytics visualization of *User Flow*, could help you answer these questions.  The chart looks like this.

[image]

([source](http://www.verticalmeasures.com/measurement-reporting/flow-visualization-visitor-and-conversion-reports-in-google-analytics/) of the picture)

More on User flow visualization [here](http://www.esotech.org/blog/how-to-use-google-analytics-visitor-flow-to-optimize-website-traffic) and [here](https://www.e-nor.com/blog/general/google-analytics-flow-visualization-not-your-traditional-path-analysis).

*p.s.*  It would also be nice if the User Flow diagram displayed the average time that users spends on each page.